# Calling a python 2.7 function in c++ using the default api?

Tags: c++, python-2.7

Say I have a function

```
def pyfunc():
    print("ayy lmao")
    return 4
```

and I want to call it in c++

```
int j = (int)python.pyfunc();
```

how exactly would I do that?

Comment: Go to your favorite search engine and search for "C++ python api", I'm sure you will something.

Comment: Tried that, proving fruitless, that's why I went here

Comment: Or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417473/call-python-from-c

Comment: So you didn't find the [Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/) or [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) (the first two links in my search) or about [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) which makes it super-easy to embed or extend Python in C++.

Comment: I just wanted some help, there's no need to be condescending about it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look into this:https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: I did and I have trouble understanding it all, is there anyway you could break it down for me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a Python function from C++, you have to *embed* Python
in your C++ application.  To do this, you have to:

1. Load the Python DLL.  How you do this is system dependent:
   `LoadLibrary` under Windows, `dlopen` under Unix.  If the Python DLL is
   in the usual path you use for DLLs (`%path%` under Windows,
   `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` under Unix), this will happen automatically if you try
   calling any function in the Python C interface.  Manual loading will
   give you more control with regards to version, etc.
2. Once the library has been loaded, you have to call the function
   `Py_Initialize()` to initialize it.  You may want to call
   `Py_SetProgramName()` or `Py_SetPythonHome()` first to establish the
   environment.
3. Your function is in a module, so you'll have to load that:
   `PyImport_ImportModule`.  If the module isn't in the standard path,
   you'll have to add its location to `sys.path`: use
   `PyImport_ImportModule` to get the module `"sys"`, then
   `PyObject_GetAttrString` to get the attribute `"path"`.  The path
   attribute is a list, so you can use any of the list functions to add
   whatever is needed to it.
4. Your function is an attribute of the module, so you use
   `PyObject_GetAttrString` on the module to get an instance of the
   function.  Once you've got that, you pack the arguments into a tuple or
   a dictionary (for keyword arguments), and use `PyObject_Call` to call
   it.

All of the functions, and everything that is necessary, is documented
(extremely well, in fact) in https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/.  You'll
be particularly interested in the sections on "Embedding Python" and
"Importing Modules", along with the more general utilities ("Object
Protocol", etc.).  You'll also need to understand the general principles
with regards to how the Python/C API works—things like reference
counting and borrowed vs. owned references; you'll probably want to read
all of the sections in the Introduction first.

And of course, despite the overall quality of the documentation, it's
not perfect.  A couple of times, I've had to plunge into the Python
sources to figure out what was going on.  (Typically, when I'm getting
an error back from Python, to find out what it's actually complaining
about.)